# AppHarbor + OWIN

Tags: mono, appharbor, owin

I'm trying to make an AppHarbor OWIN app.  I took my functioning POC standalone OWIN app and migrated it to use IIS Pipeline (trying both OwinStartup and appSettings)

As near as I can tell, the Startup is not initializing.  But, I'm not even that sure.  The build succeeds, and it copies the relevant (one) DLL.  I was getting 404's and on the / page the stock standard "nginx" page.  I modified the appSettings to point to Startup instead of (in addition to, actually) using the OwinStartup attribute, and now the / page is a 403.  It's a clue, but I'm still lost

The Startup looks like this:

```
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Extensions;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(PGO_6.Startup))]

namespace PGO_6
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            appBuilder.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                TextWriter output = context.Get<TextWriter>("host.TraceOutput");
                return next().ContinueWith(result =>
                {
                    output.WriteLine("Scheme {0} : Method {1} : Path {2} : MS {3}",
                        context.Request.Scheme, context.Request.Method, context.Request.Path, getTime());
                });
            });

            appBuilder.Run(async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(getTime() + " My First OWIN App");
            });

            // Configure Web API
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", 
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        static string getTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

So, almost totally boiler plate code.  The {controller} part is direct from my other functioning POC.  The other is a direct copy from an MSDN example.

Any advice how I can move this towards functioning?  Thank you!

p.s. developing this under the Xamarin environment, targeting .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the AppHarbor support is great.  He helped me discover:

- targetFramework must be set in web.config compilation block.  Rookie mistake on my part
- some .config files weren't getting copied over during the AppHarbor build, because I neglected to tag the files with proper build action/copy attributes.  Another rookie mistake on my part

Those were the main issues.  Works great now